Virtual Machine Scale Set HDD vs SSD
We use a Virtual Machine Scale Set in Azure which is deployed in westeurope. We checked the box to use an Ephemeral OS disk placed on the Temp disk. I assumed that this is always SSD storage.
In the VMSS disk property however we see Standard HDD:
Screenshot of the disk property
When changing this in code to use SSD the VMSS is updated properly. After this we see SSD in the disk properties but spawning instances failes with the error:
Storage account types other than Standard_LRS are not supported in this region westeurope.
Is this a VMSS thing or specific for Westeurope and if so, what region does support SSD storage?
Thanks in advance for thinking with me.
Regards Nathan

It's not a region-specific thing. Ephemeral OS disks are supported in all regions, and they always use high-speed SSDs attached to the physical VM hosts.
It appears that the validation routines when updating a VMSS are not as stringent as those performed when submitting a deployment to ARM.
You can disregard the OS disk type displayed in a VMSS when the ephemeral option is configured. The only option in ARM that can be changed is placement. This must have a value of ResourceDisk for temp disk, or CacheDisk for OS cache:
        "osDisk": {
          "diffDiskSettings": {
            "option": "Local" ,
            "placement": "ResourceDisk"
          },
          "caching": "ReadOnly",
          "createOption": "FromImage"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/ephemeral-os-disks-deploy#scale-set-template-deployment
